# List/Vector iterator wont change const reference attribute in a derived class

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdlist

new to c++. I dont know (cant find the right search terms) why the following happens.

Basically the `Parent` class has a member `inputs`. The `Child` class has a const reference to `Parent::inputs` and a `Child::set_inputs()` method to alter `Parent::inputs`. When I have a `std::list<Child>` or `std::vector<Child>`  to which i iterate through and attempt to `set_inputs`,
`Parent::inputs` changes but `Child::input` does not. Whats happening behind the scenes and how would i work my way through this? as I would need to work with lists/vectors.

```
class Parent {

public:
    Parent() = default;
protected:
    double inputs;
};

class Child : public Parent {

public:

    Child() = default;

    void set_inputs(const double& X) {
        inputs = X;
    }

public:
    const double& input = inputs;
};

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    // Without Lists, works outputs '3.0'
    double X1 = 3.0;
    Child test0;
    test0.set_inputs(X1);
    cout << test0.input << endl;


    // Neither Lists or Vectors work, does not output '3.0'
    Child test1, test2, test3;
    std::list<Child> test_lists = { test1, test2, test3 };
    for (std::list<Child>::iterator t = test_lists.begin(); t != test_lists.end(); ++t) {
        t->set_inputs(X1);
        cout << t->input << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default copy-ctor is establishing the reference `input` from one instance to another. You're making copies of your child objects when you put them in your container. In other words, the `input` members of your container copies still reference the `inputs` members of you `test1`, `test`, etc. instances. Therefore when calling `set_inputs` to change the instances `Parent::inputs` member (which is happening), it has nothing to do with the `inputs` that is being referenced by `input` in those contained `Child` objects. Note: this is also a recipe for a dangling reference just waiting in the wings, if `test1` etc go out of scope before your container.

Put another way, the default copy ctor is doing this:

```
Child(const Child& c) : Parent(c), input(c.input) {}
```

Ouch. now that `input` member is referencing whatever `c.input` referenced; not `Parent::inputs` .

To see what happens without copying change the decl you can do this: `std::list<Child> test_lists(3);` . Now when you run your program it will run "correctly". There are no copies being made, therefore no mis-wires of the `input` reference member.

To address this, you need to make sure that the `input` member is always pinned to its parent `inputs`, including on copy-ctor. In short, add this:

`Child(const Child& c) : Parent(c), input(inputs)  {}`

to the `Child` class.